# Can an EU citizen under 25 years old enter Musee d'Orsay through entrance C?

Tags: bookings, paris, museums

According to [this page](https://musee-orsay.fnacspectacles.com/place-spectacle/manifestation/Musee-MUSEE-D-ORSAY---ENTREE-JOURNEE-ORSAY.htm), entry to the Musee d'Orsay is free for "18-25 year olds who are citizens or long-term residents of an EU member state", without reservation.

Can they also enter directly through entrance C (without a ticket)? Or do they have to take the "long queue"?

Comment: I am not sure, but in most museums I visited, including french ones, you have to take the long queue, in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally the answer is **yes**, everyone who is eligible to enter without reservation according to their rules can go directly through entrance C. 
It's sufficient to just show a valid ID to prove your age.
This also applies to other museums in Paris which use this policy (e.g. Musée de l'Orangerie).

However I could not find any written advice for this neither on their page nor on site but the security staff was very helpful to just ask and pass.